# In Safari svg mask looks blurry like if it's raster

Tags: css, ios, svg, safari

In Safari but not in Chrome applying svg mask on svg icon renders blurry edges. I've created minimal reproducible example... at least I hope that it's reproducible. Because this effect is not constant:

- some random changes in unrelated parts of a page can "fix" the bug.
- after these changes if I refresh the page - the bug disappears or reappears at random. Sometimes the switch happens when I duplicate a tab, or open the page in a new tab manually entering the url in the address bar, or when I open a new private window . Probably some cache magic.

I've tried it on desktop in 15.6.1 and 16.4 and in webviews on an assortment of Apple mobile devices.

The actual result:

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .logo {
        width: 96px;
        height: 96px;
        -webkit-mask-size: contain;
        mask-size: contain;
        -webkit-mask-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PG1hc2sgaWQ9ImEiIHN0eWxlPSJtYXNrLXR5cGU6YWxwaGEiIG1hc2tVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSI0OCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTQ4IDI0YzAgMTkuMjA1LTQuNzk1IDI0LTI0IDI0UzAgNDMuMjA1IDAgMjQgNC43OTUgMCAyNCAwczI0IDQuNzk1IDI0IDI0eiIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIvPjwvbWFzaz48ZyBtYXNrPSJ1cmwoI2EpIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMDAwIiBkPSJNMCAwaDQ4djQ4SDB6Ii8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==);
        mask-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PG1hc2sgaWQ9ImEiIHN0eWxlPSJtYXNrLXR5cGU6YWxwaGEiIG1hc2tVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSI0OCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTQ4IDI0YzAgMTkuMjA1LTQuNzk1IDI0LTI0IDI0UzAgNDMuMjA1IDAgMjQgNC43OTUgMCAyNCAwczI0IDQuNzk1IDI0IDI0eiIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIvPjwvbWFzaz48ZyBtYXNrPSJ1cmwoI2EpIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMDAwIiBkPSJNMCAwaDQ4djQ4SDB6Ii8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==);
        background-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iIzAwMCIgZD0iTTAgMGgyMHYyMEgweiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
            background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**SVGs**

1. The mask:

```html
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="mask0_16513_8424" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48">
<path d="M48 24C48 43.2052 43.2052 48 24 48C4.79475 48 0 43.2052 0 24C0 4.79475 4.79475 0 24 0C43.2052 0 48 4.79475 48 24Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_16513_8424)">
<rect width="48" height="48" fill="black"/>
</g>
<defs>
</defs>
</svg>
```

2. The icon:

```html
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="20" height="20" fill="#000000"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, safari has problems with `mask-images` containing masked elements.

Fortunately you can simplify your mask:

```css
.logo {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='48' height='48' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 48 48' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cmask id='a' style='mask-type:alpha' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x='0' y='0' width='48' height='48'%3E%3Cpath d='M48 24c0 19.205-4.795 24-24 24S0 43.205 0 24 4.795 0 24 0s24 4.795 24 24z' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Cg mask='url(%23a)'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000' d='M0 0h48v48H0z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.logo2 {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='48' height='48' viewBox='0 0 48 48'%3E%3Cpath d='M48 24c0 19.205-4.795 24-24 24S0 43.205 0 24 4.795 0 24 0s24 4.795 24 24z' fill='%23000' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
     
}
```

```html
<p>Original</p>
<div class="logo"></div>
<p>Fixed</p>
<div class="logo2"></div>
```

Your mask svg can be reduced to the mask shape itself:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <path d="M48 24c0 19.205-4.795 24-24 24S0 43.205 0 24 4.795 0 24 0s24 4.795 24 24z" fill="#000" />
</svg>
```

You can also use [Yoksel's data-URL converter](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).
This way, your data-URL is more readable.

Comment: Thanx. It works. At least on some versions. I'll accept the answer after thorough testing

Answer (score 1):

Safari has some problems with resizing SVG images, in the case the `viewBox` attribute is missing.
I can't tell if this is an intended behaviour or some sort of bug. But it's around for a while now.
Adding the attribute on your above example, fixed that behaviour and the mask gets a crisp edge.

Not sure why other changes on your page randomly seem to "fix" or "break" the mask (in terms of blurriness).

---

Your SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" fill="none">
...
</svg>
```

With viewport property

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" fill="none" viewbox="0 0 48 48">
...
</svg>
```

---

And working example based on your code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .logo {
        width: 96px;
        height: 96px;
        -webkit-mask-size: contain;
        mask-size: contain;
        -webkit-mask-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI0OCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld2JveD0iMCAwIDQ4IDQ4Ij48bWFzayBpZD0iYSIgc3R5bGU9Im1hc2stdHlwZTphbHBoYSIgbWFza1VuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjQ4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQ4Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNNDggMjRjMCAxOS4yMDUtNC43OTUgMjQtMjQgMjRTMCA0My4yMDUgMCAyNCA0Ljc5NSAwIDI0IDBzMjQgNC43OTUgMjQgMjR6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIi8+PC9tYXNrPjxnIG1hc2s9InVybCgjYSkiPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiIGQ9Ik0wIDBoNDh2NDhIMHoiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+);
        mask-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI0OCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0OCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgdmlld2JveD0iMCAwIDQ4IDQ4Ij48bWFzayBpZD0iYSIgc3R5bGU9Im1hc2stdHlwZTphbHBoYSIgbWFza1VuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjQ4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQ4Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNNDggMjRjMCAxOS4yMDUtNC43OTUgMjQtMjQgMjRTMCA0My4yMDUgMCAyNCA0Ljc5NSAwIDI0IDBzMjQgNC43OTUgMjQgMjR6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIi8+PC9tYXNrPjxnIG1hc2s9InVybCgjYSkiPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiIGQ9Ik0wIDBoNDh2NDhIMHoiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+);
        background-image:
            url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iIzAwMCIgZD0iTTAgMGgyMHYyMEgweiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
            background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting point. There's no `viewBox` in css, but there is one in the original SVG mask. Haven't noticed it, thanx. Probably some build tool issue. But... I don't see any difference in my two versions of Safari with your fix. Have you tried to zoom in?

Comment: Yes, I zoomed in to maximum in both versions, yours and mine. Your version is blurry, mine is not. Maybe a difference in Safari version? I'm currently using `Version 15.1 (17612.2.9.1.20)`

Comment: Oh and just a note, the `viewBox` attribute is specific to the SVG (html) element. You won't find it in CSS

Comment: I don't have 15.1 but I checked on 13.1.2, 15.6, 16.1 - no difference. So maybe you "fix" is the result of the randomness I've described in the question.

About `viewBox` I've meant that if you'll decode `url(data:` from the posted html snippet - there's no `viewBox`, but this `url(data:` is generated from svg file that has it (also posted in the question)

Comment: Vector is supposed to be dynamic size though :-/ 

How can we do that without manually declaring sizes?